# MBA From Edinburgh Business School in USA?

Tags: hiring-process, human-resources, education, hiring

I was wondering how this would be looked at in the USA. I've heard in placed where foreign degrees don't matter and I've heard that they do.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

https://www.ebsglobal.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This school, at least the Edinburgh part, has a royal charter accreditation which is the UK equivalent of a department of education endorsement.  As such I would assume that it would be recognized as a legitimate degree along with any other accredited school.  As the USA is allied with the UK and there are already prestigious recognized schools there I think it would be accepted just fine.  Usually the issue comes when the school has no formal backing from a board of education to validate them and this is not the case with this school.